# Remotely tracking room temperature with smartphone, tablet or laptop

Tags: temperature

I need a way to remotely monitor the temperature of my room. It is very important to know (for health reasons) the temperature of a specific room in my home. In the future I will also look for a way to adjust the thermostat of the room or turn A/C on/off depending on the situation but now I am looking for a way to simply track the temperature of a room remotely using smartphone, tablet or laptop. Any of the three would suffice.

Comment: Are you looking for DIY or Out-of-box?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long is it customizable

Comment: This is one example for Oob: https://www.rwe-smarthome.de/web/cms/en/457156/smarthome/information/what-is-rwe-smarthome/ They have a temperature package: https://www.rwe-smarthome.de/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/RWEEffizienz-SmartHome-Site/en_EN/-/EUR/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductUUID=heUKaASGB7gAAAFIlMM69g02&CatalogCategoryID=4fQKlwsg0dUAAAEyr5VSjdzx (sorry, only found the german version). But I think there are many other producers.

Comment: It seems to suite my needs thanks. If you found the temperature package in English as-well and put it all in an answer then I would accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on the cheap and can afford running wires there is a cheap & efficient solution :

- [Rasperry Pi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LPESRUK) ( Appx $40 )
- [Dallas 1-wire DS18B20 sensors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M2S564I) ( Appx $2.5 each )
- Spare Wire

The sensors can be connected to the Pi without requiring an external adapter, then you can run a Home Automation supervisor such as [OpenHAB](http://www.openhab.org/) to monitor it and triggers various actions with the inputs.

Answer (score 7):

For DIY you could use a [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) with a [RaZberry](http://razberry.z-wave.me/) (z-wave module for the Pi).

RaZberry comes with a web-app and mobile apps. But **you** have to bring your controlling web-app into the net and care about the security!

This way you can use standard z-wave products. In this case a radiator thermostat.

Answer (score 4):

One example for an out-of-the-box solution is [RWE Smarthome](https://www.rwe-smarthome.de/web/cms/en/457156/smarthome/information/what-is-rwe-smarthome/)

They have a special [temperature package](https://www.rwe-smarthome.de/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/RWEEffizienz-SmartHome-Site/en_EN/-/EUR/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductUUID=heUKaASGB7gAAAFIlMM69g02&CatalogCategoryID=4fQKlwsg0dUAAAEyr5VSjdzx), but unfortunately their shop seems to be in German only.

There is another solution by [Devolo](http://www.reichelt.de/Devolo-Home-Cpontrol/DEVOLO-9362/3/index.html?&ACTION=3&LA=2&ARTICLE=149368&GROUPID=3874&artnr=DEVOLO+9362).

Both of them use portal you connect to, and offer mobile apps to control your system.

But I think there are many other producers/distributors.

Comment: nothing in english or greek? :P

Comment: No, sorry. But the pages about the devolo HomeControl are in english. And as far as I know they integrate well with thier Powerline. (If that is interesting for you.)

Comment: Maybe I should go for a DIY project instead

Answer (score 3):

If you have a z-wave based home automation system like me, you can use :

- http://www.vesternet.com/z-wave-everspring-temperature-and-humidity-sensor (very accurate)
- http://www.vesternet.com/z-wave-aeon-labs-multisensor (always reports the temperature a few degrees higher than the actual temperature, but it comes with other sensors built-in)

There are also equivalent temperature sensors for other types of home automation protocols.

Alternatively if you're looking for a solution that works on your phone without an external sensor and you have a phone that supports it, like the Galaxy S4 or Note 3, you should try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sensirion.ambientsensing&hl=en. However, this approach is generally off by a few degrees also, but it is completely free if you happen to have the right devices. :) If you google what the temperature offset is, you could just guess what the actual temperature is.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.smarthome.com/la-crosse-technology-server-room-wireless-temperature-and-humidity-monitor.html plus many others on [smarthome.com](http://www.smarthome.com)

Another solution is to get an insteon thermostat at smarthome with a universal devices [ISY 994i series](https://www.universal-devices.com/residential/isy994i-series/) controller will allow for advanced automation in the future.

(disclaimer: I have many insteon devices and a universal devices controller but no experience with thermostats)

(I am also considering moving to an open-source home automation system for advanced scripting capabilities, though the ISY is quite adequate for most applications and has less of a learning-curve)

Comment: This specific devices costs extra to send emails to you as noted by the reviews

Answer (score 2):

[Smart Things](http://www.smartthings.com) offers a [temperature sensor](https://shop.smartthings.com/#!/packs/smartsense-multi/).[image: Smart Things multi-sensor]

You could then use their system to have it report the temperature to their ecosystem with alerts if it goes below or above a certain point as well as looking at it any time you would want from anywhere.  For extra bonus, you could hook it up to [Xively](http://www.xively.com) and get graphs out of the system.